# ::-ms-thumb appears behind track

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have created a custom class for some sliders.In chrome everything is working fine.See image below:

Chrome

[image]

My problem though is that on internet explorer i get this:
[image]

Now here is my css:

```
input[type="range"].slider-black::-ms-thumb{
height:40px;
width:40px;
border-radius:100px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
border:2px solid silver;
box-shadow:0 0 4px 2px rgba(1,1,1,0.8);

}



    input[type="range"].slider-black::-webkit-slider-thumb{
height:40px;
width:40px;
border-radius:100px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
border:2px solid silver;
box-shadow:0 0 4px 2px rgba(1,1,1,0.8);

}
```

Is there any way to do my ::-ms-thumb look exactly the same as it is on chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
The trick is to apply a margin, half the width of thumb-button, in the ::-ms-track.
here's an online [demo](https://googledrive.com/host//0B8BLd2qPPV7XMHR3MGVVbFQ4V3M/input-type-range-ms-css--inp2-thumb.html)