# ::-ms-thumb appears behind track in MS Edge

Tags: css, less, range, microsoft-edge

I have created a slider.

In chrome everything is working fine.See image below:
[image]

But in MS Edge, thumb appears behind track. See image below:
[image]

I created a codepen to explain and show my problem : https://codepen.io/glalloue/pen/QGKqNd

Css(less) applied :

```
.form input[type=range] {
    z-index: 1;
    align-self: stretch;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
                appearance: none;
        border: none;
        width: 2.5rem;
        height: 2.5rem;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #cccccc, 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    &::-ms-thumb {
        appearance: none;
        border: none;
        width: 2.5rem;
        height: 2.5rem;
        background-color: pink;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #C0C0C0, 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }
}
```

Here is a similar question with internet explorer : [::-ms-thumb appears behind track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011717/ms-thumb-appears-behind-track)
Suggested solution was to add margin to ::-ms-track but without success.

Is there any way to do my ::-ms-thumb in MS edge look exactly the same as it is on chrome?

Comment: you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517158/z-index-in-internet-explorer-not-working

Comment: @Rahul : I'm not sure to understand what to use in your link.
I tried to set z-index on -ms-thumb but nothing happen,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is (indirectly) `background-image` on input :

```
<input name="perimeter" id="perimeter" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%, rgba(164, 223, 253, 0.8) 1%, rgba(164, 223, 253, 0.8) 25%, black 26%, black 100%);" type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1" value="1">
```

This `background-image` is necessary to set colors before and after thumb on Chrome and Safari.

To resolve problem, i need to set height value on css `.form input[type=range]`.
But if i do it, background-image take all the height value.
It's working on Chrome, but not on MS edge.

So, to resolve it, it's necessary to use MS Edge Browser specificities :

1. Remove `background-image` on input.
2. Add css styles : `-ms-fill-lower` and `-ms-fill-upper` to set colors before and after thumb

Result is :

```
<!-- Android & iOS -->
<input id="perimeter" type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1" style="background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%, rgba(164,223,253,0.8) 1%, rgba(164,223,253,0.8) {{ perimeter *100 / (distances.length -1) | number:0 }}%, black {{ perimeter *100 / (distances.length -1) + 1 | number:0 }}%, black 100%)"/>
<!-- Windows -->
<input id="perimeter" type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1" style="height: 2.5rem;"/>
```

You need to condition input display. If you use angular, use `ng-if` to display first input only on android and ios, and second on windows.

and less file is :

```
@thumb-color: white;
@thumb-radius: 50%;
@thumb-height: 2.5rem;
@thumb-width: 2.5rem;

@track-width: 100%;
@track-height: 3px;
@track-fill-lower-color: rgba(164,223,253,0.8);
@track-fill-upper-color: black;

.track() {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: @track-width;
    height: @track-height;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb() {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: @thumb-height;
    width: @thumb-width;
    border-radius: @thumb-radius;
    background: @thumb-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px grey, 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: @thumb-height/2 0;
  width: @track-width;

  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    .track();
    border: none;
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    .thumb();
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -1.25rem; // @thumb-height / 2
  }

  &::-moz-range-track {
     .track();
     border: none;
  }
  &::-moz-range-thumb {
     .thumb();
  }

  &::-ms-track {
    .track();
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
  }
  &::-ms-thumb {
    .thumb();
  }
  &::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: @track-fill-lower-color;
  }
  &::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: @track-fill-upper-color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case removing `background-image` and defining lower and upper backgrounds didn't work. So if anybody is still looking for it, this is what worked in my case.

The problem was the height of the range element. It is set as 2px and range track height 2.5em.

Here's a **Codepen demo** with a working example in the edge
https://codepen.io/piyukore06/pen/abbqJGK?editors=1111